# scandir/opendir wont work with ssh2.sftp?

Tags: php, scandir, ssh2-sftp

if i try the following command:

```
$_content = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/Lorem-62398848890105_20190117-101229.txt");
```

it works and i get the correct content.
But whenever I want to have all the files of the remote folder, the directory can not be opened.

I tried *scandir* or *opendir*. Both of these raises this message:

```
Warning: scandir(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://12/ on remote host
```

What im doing wrong? Some tips would really help me.

Regards

Context: I use PHP 7.0.32 and ssh2.so is fully installed

---

**UPDATE:** I got it. I think it is due to a wrong attitude of the provider.
How it works:

```
$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp).ssh2_sftp_realpath($sftp,".").'./');
```

The function *ssh2_sftp_realpath* + '*./*' do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps this web page may be of help http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php

Comment: I can connect via ssh2.sftp to reach one file. But I need the whole directory and do not always know the filenames.

Comment: There is an example in the above web page to do this

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for your help Ed